# Is it possible to manage JobObjects by name only, without keeping an open HANDLE?

Tags: c, windows, process, handle, jobs

With processes, I can do the following:

```
int pid;
::CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, ..., &pi);
pid = pi.dwProcessId;
::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
// then later...
HANDLE proc = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, pid);
::TerminateProcess(proc, 1);
::CloseHandle(proc);
```

In this fashion, I can manage windows processes by pid only, which is nice for multi-platform code.

I would like to extend this pattern to job objects:

```
HANDLE job = ::CreateJobObject(NULL, name);
::AssignProcessToJobObject(job, proc); // proc from above
::CloseHandle(job);
// then later...
job = ::OpenJobObject(JOB_OBJECT_TERMINATE, FALSE, name);
::TerminateJobObject(job, 1);
```

To be clear, I am not in the job, but my child process is. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "The job is destroyed when its last handle has been closed and all associated processes have exited". In this case, my main process has closed his last handle, but the child is still running, and still has a handle. A call to `IsProcessInJob(proc, NULL, &isit)` confirms the job still exists. However, my call to open the job returns NULL, and the error code is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

So the question: does my main process have any way to get a handle to the job after closing it?

Comment: You should be able to reopen the job object by name.  Can you provide a complete self-contained example program demonstrating the problem you're having?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, your comment prompted me to try a few new permutations as I was putting my small example together. You are correct, under the right circumstances, that I am able to reopen the job handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. However, observe:

```
// This example will fail to reopen and terminate the job.
// Processes cmd and ping stay running
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

// BEGIN BLOCK A
::CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul",
    NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, ".", &si, &pi);
HANDLE job = ::CeateJobObject(NULL, "myjob");
::AssignProcessToJobObject(job, pi.hProcess);
// END BLOCK A

::ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
::CloseHandle(job);
HANDLE reopenJob = ::OpenJobObject(JOB_OBJECT_TERMINATE, FALSE, "myjob");
if(reopenJob != NULL)
    ::TerminateJobObject(reopenJob, 1);
```

The reopened job in this case is NULL, and the error code is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

The job must be created before the process, and be inherited, for the job to be reopenable.

```
// NEW BLOCK A
HANDLE job = ::CreateJobObject(NULL, "myjob");
::SetHandleInformation(job, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
::CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul",
    NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, ".", &si, &pi);
::AssignProcessToJobObject(job, pi.hProcess);
```

If your goal is to name the job using the PID, note that this creation order prevents such a convention. This still means that some piece of information must be tracked in addition to the PID in order to reopen the job.

Comment: If you want to name the job using the PID, use DuplicateHandle to explicitly give the child process a copy of the handle rather than letting it inherit a copy.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the NT object manager works. Almost all objects are "temporary", which means that they are deleted when no more references to them (either kernel-mode pointer references or handles) exist. You should be able to change this behavior by calling `NtMakePermanentObject` on your job object. I haven't ever tried this before though.

Comment: This is a good answer, although it doesn't get me what I want. If I need to manage either a JobObject handle or an NT kernel object to help windows cleanup after itself, then I'll just keep ahold of the handle.

Comment: @RyanCalhoun: Oh sorry, I misread your question. Are you saying that the job object still exists but you can't open it by name?

Comment: I am not sure if the job still exists or not. The IsProcessInJob call suggests that it does. The OpenJobObject definitely does not let me open it by name. The MSDN documentation does not seem definitive regarding exactly what constitutes the last handle to the job, e.g. if the child process somehow has a handle to the job after being added to the job.

Comment: @RyanCalhoun: You can use Process Hacker, Process Explorer or WinObj to check for the existence of the job object. Double-click on the process and click the Job tab.

Comment: Using `NtMakePermanentObject` did work for me, allowing me to reopen the job by name after all handles are closed. Note however that for this function to work you need to activate the `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege`.